# Issue between Django 2.0 / Apache2 and WSGI

Tags: python, django, mod-wsgi, wsgi, django-wsgi

I'm trying to deploy my Django project in my server but I'm encountering some issues.

## My environment :

- Ubuntu 16.04 Server
- Django 2.0
- Python 3.5
- Apache2 2.4
- WSGI

## Django configuration :

My Django project is located to : `/var/www/html/DatasystemsCORE`

I have **wsgi.py** file (`/var/www/html/DatasystemsCORE/DatasystemsCORE`) which looks like :

```
import os, sys
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "DatasystemsCORE.settings")
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

I have `ALLOWED_HOST` like this :

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost', '172.30.10.86', '[::1]']
```

## Apache2 configuration :

In my **apache2.conf** file, I have :

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/DatasystemsCORE/DatasystemsCORE/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath /var/www/html/DatasystemsCORE
Alias /static/ /var/www/html/DatasystemsCORE/static/Theme/

<Directory /var/www/html/DatasystemsCORE/static/Theme/>
        Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/html/DatasystemsCORE/DatasystemsCORE>
        <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
        </Files>
</Directory>
```

And I have in **sites-available/000-default.conf** :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/DatasystemsCORE

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

To my mind, all parameters seem to be right, but when I write : **172.30.10.86:80** in my browser, I get : `500 Internal Server Error`

## Traceback

This is the Traceback given by **error.log** in apache2 :

```
[Tue Apr 24 12:07:32.526764 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 2611:tid 139723751765760] [client 172.30.10.73:50128] mod_wsgi (pid=2611): Target WSGI script '/var/www/html/DatasystemsCORE/DatasystemsCORE/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Tue Apr 24 12:07:32.526839 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 2611:tid 139723751765760] [client 172.30.10.73:50128] mod_wsgi (pid=2611): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/html/DatasystemsCORE/DatasystemsCORE/wsgi.py'.
[Tue Apr 24 12:07:32.526970 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 2611:tid 139723751765760] [client 172.30.10.73:50128] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Tue Apr 24 12:07:32.527038 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 2611:tid 139723751765760] [client 172.30.10.73:50128]   File "/var/www/html/DatasystemsCORE/DatasystemsCORE/wsgi.py", line 14, in <module>
[Tue Apr 24 12:07:32.527042 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 2611:tid 139723751765760] [client 172.30.10.73:50128]     application = get_wsgi_application()
[Tue Apr 24 12:07:32.527048 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 2611:tid 139723751765760] [client 172.30.10.73:50128]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
[Tue Apr 24 12:07:32.527050 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 2611:tid 139723751765760] [client 172.30.10.73:50128]     django.setup(set_prefix=False)
[Tue Apr 24 12:07:32.527055 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 2611:tid 139723751765760] [client 172.30.10.73:50128]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
[Tue Apr 24 12:07:32.527064 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 2611:tid 139723751765760] [client 172.30.10.73:50128]     apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
[Tue Apr 24 12:07:32.527069 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 2611:tid 139723751765760] [client 172.30.10.73:50128]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 81, in populate
[Tue Apr 24 12:07:32.527072 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 2611:tid 139723751765760] [client 172.30.10.73:50128]     raise RuntimeError("populate() isn't reentrant")
[Tue Apr 24 12:07:32.527086 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 2611:tid 139723751765760] [client 172.30.10.73:50128] RuntimeError: populate() isn't reentrant
```

I tried lots of things according to multiple stackoverflow questions, but none answer up to now.

Did I miss something with `wsgi` or `mod_wsgi` ?

## Edit

My latest apache conf file looks like :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerName DatasystemsCORE
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/DatasystemsCORE/DatasystemsCORE

WSGIPassAuthorization On
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/DatasystemsCORE/DatasystemsCORE/DatasystemsCORE.wsgi
WSGIDaemonProcess DatasystemsCORE python-home=/home/valentin python-path=/var/www/html/DatasystemsCORE
Alias /static/ /var/www/html/DatasystemsCORE/static/Theme/

<Directory /var/www/html/DatasystemsCORE/static/Theme/>
        Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/html/DatasystemsCORE/DatasystemsCORE>
        <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
        </Files>
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

## SOLUTION

`Servername` in my **apache2.conf** file should refer to my `server hostname` and not my Django project !

Comment: @Alasdair Yes `libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3` is already satisfied.

Comment: The ``populate() isn't reentrant`` is not the rot problem. You need to look into the Apache error logs for the first error, corresponding to the first request made after a process restart. That is the real error. You get the error you gave only for subsequent requests after the first, so is important to find the error for the first request.

Answer (score 2):

HI can you try the below configuration:

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

import sys   
sys.path.append('/var/www/html/DatasystemsCORE')
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "DatasystemsCORE.settings")
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Apache2 python wsgi module

> sudo apt-get install python3-pip apache2 libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName dev.example.com #your server name
        ServerAlias dev.example.com #your server alias

        DocumentRoot #your document root
        WSGIProcessGroup dev.example.com
        WSGIPassAuthorization On
        WSGIDaemonProcess dev.example.com python-home=/home/robert/django/robertenv python-path=/var/www/html/DatasystemsCORE  <Here should be your virtual env path >
        WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/DatasystemsCORE/DatasystemsCORE/wsgi.py

        Alias /static/ /var/www/html/DatasystemsCORE/static/Theme/ #static directory

        <Directory /var/www/html/DatasystemsCORE/static/Theme/>
            Require all granted
        </Directory>

        <Directory /var/www/html/DatasystemsCORE/DatasystemsCORE>
                <Files wsgi.py>
                        Require all granted
                </Files>
        </Directory>
   </VirtualHost>
```

Use above virtual host configuration

Comment: This virtual configuration should be in `apache2.conf` or `000-default.conf`?

Comment: you can use separte conf file

Comment: New .conf file and make symbolink link to sites-enabled ? Anyway, this configuration doesn't seem to work. I had the same thing up to now

Comment: create sites-avliable folder and enable site its create symbolink

Comment: Nothing change according to your answer (which is similar to my question) :/

Comment: can you add you latest apache conf

Comment: The latest apache2 conf is in my question. I don't have virtualenv because I don't need it.

Comment: you dont have virtual env,you load /usr/lib/python ??

Comment: I don't need virtual environment. It's not required to get virtualenv. `which python` gave me : `/usr/bin/python`

Comment: @Deadpool super