# Error running WSGI application , ImportError: No module named 'mysite' during hosting on pythonanywhere

Tags: django, hosting, wsgi, pythonanywhere

I am trying to deploy my Django project through the project using pythonanywhere but I am getting a problem and am really stuck. Can anyone help me with that.

I am stuck on it from 2 days.Please help me out in solving this error.

The WSGI.py configuration

```
import os
import sys

path = '/home/blogaspp/django_project'
if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(path)

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'django_project.settings'


from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

And the error that shows after I reload the Page is

```
2019-02-22 15:32:43,068: Error running WSGI application
2019-02-22 15:32:43,078: ImportError: No module named 'mysite'
2019-02-22 15:32:43,078:   File "/var/www/blogaspp_pythonanywhere_com_wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
2019-02-22 15:32:43,079:     application = get_wsgi_application()
2019-02-22 15:32:43,079: 
2019-02-22 15:32:43,079:   File "/home/blogaspp/.virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
2019-02-22 15:32:43,079:     django.setup(set_prefix=False)
2019-02-22 15:32:43,080: 
2019-02-22 15:32:43,080:   File "/home/blogaspp/.virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 19, in setup
2019-02-22 15:32:43,080:     configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
2019-02-22 15:32:43,080: 
2019-02-22 15:32:43,080:   File "/home/blogaspp/.virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 57, in __getattr__
2019-02-22 15:32:43,081:     self._setup(name)
2019-02-22 15:32:43,081: 
2019-02-22 15:32:43,081:   File "/home/blogaspp/.virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 44, in _setup
2019-02-22 15:32:43,082:     self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
2019-02-22 15:32:43,082: 
2019-02-22 15:32:43,082:   File "/home/blogaspp/.virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 107, in __init__
```

Comment: refer this https://stackoverflow.com/a/49999585/7261317

Comment: Please help me whithout refering anywhere else.Please see the above.

Comment: Could you post your setting file and the tree structure of your project?

Comment: Are you sure you're looking at the right error in the error log file?  The error refers to "mysite", and your code doesn't contain that string.   The timestamp is also a little off -- the error was from 22 February, and you posted your question on 23 Feb.  The most recent error for your website will be at the bottom of the error log file.